@eslint/config still creates an eslintrc file
I have installed eslint@9.1.0 in my project folder from npm. After running the command:
npm init @eslint/config

The package creates a .eslintrc.{js,json,..} file as I expected, but, as far as I understood, it is now but "kind of deprecated" (right?).
When I run
npx eslint .

I get an error
Oops! Something went wrong! :(
ESLint: 9.1.0
Error: Could not find config file.

if instead I run
npm init eslint/config 

so without the @, npm connects to the eslint/create-config repository, the module does not prompt me to Answer questions about my style but it does create an valid flat eslint.config.mjs file and the linter works again (also in VSCode).
I find this somehow inconsistent, and I have the feeling that I am missing something. So my question is: Is there anyway to keep working with an .eslintrc file? if not, how can I use/install the eslint/config command locally?
I checked my global modules and eslint is not listed.

@ddgg Could you please share your .eslintrc config file?

Sure! Here my .eslintrc...not sure why you need it though...

I had this problem too.
Previously, I would install ES Lint and then create the eslintrc.json config file in two steps:
npm install eslint --save-dev
npm init @eslint/config
But that now caused the error you got.
If I ran only one command: npm init @eslint/config@latest it walked me through the set-up steps and created the eslint.config.js file I needed.
